# Passing page/post title as parameter in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, forms

I'm looking for way I can pass the page/post title as a parameter from Gravity Form 1 to another Gravity form.  I'm able to pass parameters fine, but I'm looking to be able to pass the &post={post title:2} and have it grab the post/page title without having to create a custom form for every page or post.  Is there a default parameter/field name that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution to my problem and it was actually very easy to do once I found the field.  https://www.wpgarage.com/plugins/dynamic-page-url-gravity-forms-wordpress/  Gravity forms has built in page/url parameters you can populate hidden fields with.  Once I added the hidden field with the url, I was able to pass it to another hidden field on my second form via a querystring.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Hidden field to your form. Set the Default Value of your
2. Hidden field to `{embed_post:post_title`}.

Done! When the form is rendered, the post title of whatever post the form is being displayed on will be populated into your Hidden field and saved to the entry when the form is submitted.